# Keyboard shortcut to set tags

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, windows-live-writer

Is there a way, via the keyboard, to access the tags box? I can find it for my life. E.g. I have tried `alt +` and `ctrl +` and `tab`ing for ever. How do I set a tag?

Comment: NO way. but you could enable tag reminder then it should get focus automatically. it can lesser the hassle. check: http://zeek.ir/SztNJ

Comment: That's a major bummer. Thanks for the "tag reminder" tip.